# Qt - simple Http server

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qtnetwork, qtcpserver

I have written simple Http server (only for getting and parsing requests).
But it doesn't seems to work properly: sometimes i'm getting error "Access violation (c0000005)"

UPD: i have followed suggestions and changed source:

```
Server::Server()
{
    tcpServer = new QTcpServer();
    if (!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1111)) {
        return;
    }

    QObject::connect(tcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, [=]() {
        QTcpSocket *clientSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
        QObject::connect(clientSocket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, clientSocket, &QTcpSocket::deleteLater);

        QObject::connect(clientSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [this, clientSocket]() {
            const QString line = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(clientSocket->readLine());
            clientSocket->disconnectFromHost();
            const QStringList tokens = QString(line).split(QRegExp("[ \r\n][ \r\n]*"));


            if (parseParams(tokens)) {
                emit Server::newRequest(params);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Will this code never throw an error "Access violation (c0000005)"?

Comment: You are capturing the stack variable `alreadyDeleted` by reference, but the stack frame goes away very shortly (after the two calls to connect). You do not need it anyway, as the handler cannot fire if the object is already destroyed (destruction disconnects signal handlers).

Comment: Will unique_ptr fix this issue?

Comment: Just get rid of the `alreadyDeleted` variable completely. You don't need it.

Comment: In this case deleteLater() will be called few times...

Comment: It should be called 1 per each socket that disconnects. You should not get an additional disconnect signal for a socket that already disconnected.

Comment: Maybe the bug is somewhere else. Are you testing this in Visual Studio or qt-creator?

Comment: I'm testing in Qt Creator. The problem will occur after 4-5 days active server working

Comment: So maybe its already fixed or does the current code crash much faster?

Comment: No, this code works better then previous (the last version crashed in 30% of cases)

Comment: I think the bug is in code you don't show.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your question, but you may consider to use the official Qt HTTP server under development.

code: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/qthttpserver.git/

announcement: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2019/01/25/introducing-qt-http-server/

Comment: I've created an AUR package for this as well

Answer (score 0):

```
Server::run()
{
    m_server = new QTcpServer();
    m_server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1111);
    connect(m_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), SLOT(ConnectClient()));
}

Server::ConnectClient()
{
   QTcpSocket *client = m_server->nextPendingConnection();
   if(client)
   {
        client->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        QByteArray data = client->readAll();
        // you can get request
        std::string szRequest = data.toStdString(); 
        // make response
        QByteArray codSuccess = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n success";
        client->wirte(codSucces);
   }
   connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected)), client, SLOT(deleteLater()));
   client->disconnectFromHost();
}
```